# Display table after choose the selected value from dropdownlist (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display a table after the user choose selected value from dropdownlist. I have tried searching at the internet the example of the coding, but I didn't find any. My coding will be like this :

```
<select name="ddlEqu" size="1" tabindex="1" onchange="select(this.value)" id="Equddl_source">
  <option selected value="select"><--Select--></option>
  <option value="D1">T-Shirt</option>
  <option value="D2">Jacket</option>
  <option value="D3">Shoes</option>
</select>
```

If the user choose T-shirt, list of T-shirt will be display in table form. Like this :

```
ID    |  T-Shirt      | Description    | Price
1     | Mickey Mouse  | Color = Black  | RM 29.90
2     | Camera Shirt  | Color = Pink   | RM 32.50
3     |               |       = White  |
```

Can Someone help me, please...

Comment: can you please put up your select function too?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery if you can. Then you can easily pull data or what ever else you need to do. You don't even need to do select(this.value), just create a function called something like "ItemSelectedEvent".

```
var id = 0;

//This uses jquery
function ItemSelectedEvent
{
        id++;
    if($(#Equddl_source).val() == "D1") //Might also try for example (.val() == "Jacket")
    {
        $(#TableName).append("<tr><td>" + id + " | " + $(#Equddl_source).val() + " | </td></tr>");
    }
}
```

This is just a very ugly and quick example just showing sort of what you might look at. What you want is on google for sure, just keep trying. This should give you a good enough jump start.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must be loading all the tables on page load. Say you have 3 hidden tables for Items D1, D2 and D3 having ID table_D1, table_D2 and table_D3 resp. If tables are not loaded already then you should probably fetch the data via [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

```
$('#Equddl_source').change(function () {
   $('#table_' + this.value).show();       
});
```